# Not able to run JavaScript test inside Docker container

Tags: javascript, docker, npm, nvm

I have tried few of the available docker containers that has the google-chrome installed. Trying to run it in headless mode. few of the tried images are:

- selenium/standalone-chrome
- zenika/alpine-chrome

**Installed nvm and all necessary packages**

> When running the commands to start test or build, it simply gets stuck
>   forever.

```
npm test
```

or

```
npm run build
```

**This is the configuration in testee.json**

```
{
    "port": 3621,
    "root": ".",
    "reporter": "Spec",
    "timeout": 120,
    "delay": 1000,
    "tunnel": {
        "type": "local"
    },
    "launch": {
        "type": "local"
    },
    "browsers": [{
        "browser": "chrome",
        "args": [
            "--headless",
            "--disable-gpu",
            "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
        ]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need add '--no-sandbox' to browsers -> args object in your testee.json

```
{
      "port": 3621,
      "root": ".",
      "reporter": "Spec",
      "timeout": 120,
      "delay": 1000,
      "tunnel": {
          "type": "local"
      },
      "launch": {
          "type": "local"
      },
      "browsers": [{
          "browser": "chrome",
          "args": [
              "--headless",
              "--no-sandbox',
              "--disable-gpu",
              "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
          ]
      }]
}
```

For more information [Click here](https://hackernoon.com/running-karma-tests-with-headless-chrome-inside-docker-ae4aceb06ed3)